# Show that e: U $\to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathit{f} \to \mathit{f}(5)$, is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not really sure where to start with this problem. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated. The full question is as follows:

Let U = $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Show that e: U $\to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathit{f} \to \mathit{f}(5)$, is linear

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried? Have you checked the definition of linearity and looked at how you might verify $e$ meets that definition?

Comment: Thanks Nicholas! I understand that the definition of linearity implies that a function must be closed under the sum of two functions and multiplication by a scalar but I'm a little confused about what e: U $\to \mathbb{R}$ means. Does this mean that the codomain of e is $\mathbb{R}$? Also is $\mathit{f}$  just an arbitrary function in e?

Comment: Another question I have is how to interpret the line $\mathit{e}$: U $\to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathit{f} \to \mathit{f}$(5)?

Comment: $e$'s a function mapping elements in $U$ to elements in $\mathbb{R}$, and the elements in $U$ are functions, so yeah $f$ is just some real-valued function. Given an input $f$, we send it to the real number $f(5)$. It's the usual function notation, just a little weird because of the strange domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f,g \in U$, i.e. $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Now $e(f+g)=(f+g)(5)=f(5)+g(5)=e(f)+e(g)$ by definition of sum of two functions.

Now let $a \in \mathbb{R}$: we have $e(af)=(af)(5)=a(f(5))=a \cdot e(f)$ by definition of multiplication of a function by a scalar.

This proves $e$ is linear.

Comment: Appreciate the help! This makes sense, I suppose I was confused about some of the terminology involved in the problem.